# Mule ESB problems with interceptor-stack

Tags: mule, interceptor

I'm new to Mule and having trouble with using interceptor-stack elements.

The following seems like it is taken right out of their documentation here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/33X/Using+Interceptors

```
<interceptor-stack name="default">
    <logging-interceptor/>
    <timer-interceptor/>
</interceptor-stack>

<flow name="MyFlowFlow1" doc:name="MyFlowFlow1">

    <interceptor-stack ref="default"/>  <!--this is line 15 -->
    <logger level="INFO" message="Got here"/>

</flow>
```

but I get an exception saying it's invalid.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 15; columnNumber: 43; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'interceptor-stack'. One of '{"http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":annotations, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":description, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-source, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-inbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-outbound-endpoint, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":abstract-mixed-content-message-processor, "http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core":response}' is expected.
at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
...etc...
```

**EDIT - This is to address the responses below.**

This first private flow works perfectly when invoked from another flow via flow-ref.  I see the "got here" message and the timing.

```
<flow name="test2Flow1" doc:name="test2Flow1">
    <timer-interceptor/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="got here" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

However, this second private flow does not work when invoked from another flow...in fact, it won't even parse.  The only difference is that the explicit use of the timer-interceptor is changed to be a reference to an interceptor-stack containing the timer-interceptor.

```
<interceptor-stack name="default">
    <timer-interceptor/>
</interceptor-stack>

<flow name="test2Flow1" doc:name="test2Flow1">
    <interceptor-stack ref="default"/>
    <logger level="INFO" message="got here" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your flow is invalid because it doesnt have a message processor.

Take a look on the anatomy of a flow.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Flows+for+Service+Orchestration#UsingFlowsforServiceOrchestration-TheAnatomyofaFlow

Comment: There's a logger, which is a processor.  Besides, this is just a cut down version of the real thing which does quite a bit of work.  If I put the two interceptors in the flow directly, it works fine.  If I try to use an interceptor stack, it fails with a SAX parsing error.

Comment: in this case, i can only think that you can`t use the interceptor-stack right in the flow, try Seba's approaching

Answer (score 0):

Your message processor must be the first item in the flow

Comment: That's not true in general.  Are you saying it's true specifically for interceptor-stack instances?  I'll edit the post (since I can't put code here easily) and show what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Interceptors are meant to be used within components.
This configuration should work:

```
<interceptor-stack name="default">
    <logging-interceptor/>
    <timer-interceptor/>
</interceptor-stack>

<flow name="test2Flow1" doc:name="test2Flow1">
    <pooled-component class="com.MyComponent">
        <interceptor-stack ref="default"/>  <!--this is line 15 -->
    </pooled-component>
    <logger level="INFO" message="Got here"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: I'm trying to think through that.  The interceptors I want to put into a stack are based upon AbstractEnvelopeInterceptor to catch when the flow is entered and exited.  I've got one of those working when it's the first element inside the flow without putting it inside a component.  So, you're saying that, if I want more than one, I have to build a dummy component just hold a stack of interceptors? The Mule documentation at the URL I listed above gives an example of otherwise.